# how to override a task making it depend on one of mine in gradle

Tags: gradle

I tried following the gradle manual with their example like this but copyJars is not run at all before the eclipse task.  (the eclipse task comes from the eclipse plugin)

```
task('copyJars') { 

    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
    copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
    copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
}

eclipse.dependsOn = copyJars

task('setupAll', dependsOn: 'eclipse') {
    description = 'Update jars from remote repositories and then fix eclipse classpath for stbldfiles project'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with this build script:

- `eclipse` doesn't refer to the task but to the equally named model object. (Don't you get an exception for `eclipse.dependsOn`?)
- Task `copyJars` does its work in the configuration phase rather than the execution phase (i.e for every build, even if the task isn't executed)

To fix that, use `tasks.eclipse.dependsOn(copyJars)` and `task copyJars << { ... }`.

Another question is if there isn't a simpler way than copying things around with `copyJars` and fixing up the Eclipse class path after the fact, but I'd need more information to be able to tell.