# tasks.setupAll.dependsOn(copyJars) does not work in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I tried following the answer here

[how to override a task making it depend on one of mine in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128540/how-to-override-a-task-making-it-depend-on-one-of-mine-in-gradle)

but it fails with

> Could not find property 'setupAll' on task set.

I have tried a few things

1. Make the task in subprojects section depend on master:copyJars but that fails
2. The below solution
3. stripped off the tasks which didn't work.

I have only ONE build.gradle file and the settings.gradle file.  The settings gradle file is

```
include 'master', 'toneserver','webserver'
```

The master build.gradle file is(**SPECIFICALLY, search for the two instances of setupAll as somehow there is something wrong with that**)

```
//NOTE: Currently this file is for dependency management only but we would like
// to convert all of the build to gradle from the ant files.  We needed to add dependency 
// management so did so with gradle first as a first step in the process of evolution

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    buildDir = 'output'

    task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
    build << { task -> println "MASTER: I'm building now classpath=$sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.files" }
}

project(':toneserver') {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')

        compile project(':master')
        compile project(':webserver')
    }

    task eclipse(overwrite: true) {
    }

}

project(':webserver') {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')

        compile project(':master')
    }

    //playframework has it's own generation of .classpath and .project fils so do not 
    //overwrite their versions
    task eclipse(overwrite: true) {
    }
}

project(':master') {
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('lib')
    project.ext.fixedLibDir = file('libother')

    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.hibernate',   name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.4.Final'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'slf4j-api',               version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'log4j-over-slf4j',        version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback',  name: 'logback-core',            version: '1.0.6'
        compile group: 'joda-time',       name: 'joda-time',               version: '2.1'
        compile group: 'com.google.inject',name: 'guice',                  version: '3.0'
        compile group: 'com.google.protobuf',name: 'protobuf-java',        version: '2.4.1'


        //to be erased soon
        compile group: 'commons-configuration',name:'commons-configuration',version: '1.8'
        compile group: 'org.jboss.netty', name: 'netty',                   version: '3.2.7.Final'

        //compile group: 'org.asteriskjava',name: 'asterisk-java',         version: '1.0.0.M3'            
        compile fileTree(dir: project.ext.fixedLibDir, include: '*.jar')
    }

    task('copyJars') { 
        ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
        delete ext.collection
        copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
        copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
    }

        tasks.setupAll.dependsOn(copyJars)
}

subprojects {
    version = 'Developer-Build'

    //configurations.compile {
    //  exclude group: 'javax.jms',        module: 'jms'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk',     module: 'jmxtools'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx',      module: 'jmxri'
    //}

    task('setupAll', dependsOn: ['eclipse']) {
        description = 'Update jars from remote repositories and then fix eclipse classpath for master project'

    }

    hello << {println "- I depend on stserver"}

    build << { println "subproject:source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs" }
}

task release << { println "putting together release" }

//TODO: have a release task AND if version is null when running the release task
//throw an exception telling the user to pass in a version with "./build -Dversion=xxxx"
//The automated build will call the release task with a version number like that
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(release) && version == 'Developer-Build') {
        throw new StopExecutionException("You must specify -Dversion=<some version> to run the release task")
    } else {
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

What is going on with this?  Overriding tasks to depend on other stuff should work pretty easily I though(maybe that syntax is still wrong?)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, stupid mistake, forgot my task was in subprojects and should be outside and needed a : as well so new setupAll is outside subprojects and is

```
task('setupAll', dependsOn: [':master:copyJars', 'eclipse']) {
    description = 'Update jars from remote repositories and then fix eclipse classpath for master project'

}
```